# Como seleccionar el primer Objeto Json?

Tags: jquery, json

Deseo seleccionar el primer objeto independiente de los que hayan.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
getOrderForm().done(function(orderForm) {
  var items = orderForm.items;
  $.each(items, function(i, item) {
     var products = item.productCategories;
     console.log(products);
  });
});
```

como cambian dependiendo la categoría no puedo seleccionarlo de esta forma

```
console.log(products[15]);
console.log(products[14]);
```

De que forma podría hacerlo?

Comment: Supongo que `items` es una lista. Si quieres el primer elemento de la lista sería tan simple como `const categoriasPrimerItem = items[0].productCategories;`. Saludos

Comment: lastimosamente esa fue la primera opción que tuve y sale undifined

Comment: Hace falta ver qué contiene `items`. Haz clic en [edit] y agrega más información a tu pregunta. Saludos

Comment: Ya esta editada

Comment: Deseas seleccionar el primer objeto ¿de qué?.

Comment: Ya lo solucione, muchas gracias.

Comment: Pues agrega tu la respuesta para que la comunidad la vea y entienda como lo arreglastes.